# How to split definition and declaration with friend function and inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, struct, declaration, friend

I need to compile something like this:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void func1()=0;
    // ...
    friend void Derived::func2(Base *base);
private:
    int some_private;
}

struct Derived : Base {
    virtual func3()=0;
    // ...
    void func2(Base *child) {
        std::cout << child->some_private;
    }
};
```

But I keep getting compilation error. I tried swapping structures or declaring them first, but I can't declare Derived first (because of inheritance), and I can't declare Base first (because I need to declare friend function in Derived). What to do?

Comment: Consider friending the whole `struct Derived`, or replacing `private` with `protected`.

Comment: @Frank -- making `some_private` `protected` wouldn't allow `child->some_private` in `func2`. Objects of derived types have access to **their own** inherited protected members, but not to other objects' protected members.

Comment: You've got a chicken-and-egg problem. You can't add member functions in a `friend` declaration; the compiler has to have seen the definition of `Derived` in order for `Derived::func2` to be valid. It's different with non-member functions, where a `friend declaration` also serves as a declaration of that function. So, best bet is to declare `Derived` a friend.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks for the info, I would have expected that to be consistent with `private` access to members of other instances.

Comment: @Frank -- yeah, that's the natural expectation. `protected` is different, and I don't remember off the top of my head why that is, but there's a good reason for it.

Comment: Are you asking about the single downvote?  I don't recommend focusing on a single downvote.  It could be argued that the code you post produces _lots_ of unrelated errors, but I am not making that argument.  It's merely a guess.

Comment: So far, one person dislikes the question. Could be the same person who lodged the "Needs debugging details" close-vote, but there's no way for us plebes to know for sure.

Comment: Sort of feels like a backwards version of the [NVI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-virtual_interface_pattern) pattern, which separates out the public facing API from the derived class facing virtual/override API.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a few basic solutions. The most obvious is to change from private to protected. In C++, protected means subclasses have access.

You can add more public (perhaps protected) accessor methods instead.

You can forward-reference the entire Derived class and friend the entire class.

Personally, I have never felt a need to use friend methods or classes, and I don't know under what circumstances I'd have to be in before I wouldn't depend on other ways to accomplish whatever I'm trying to accomplish.

For this particular solution, I'd change the access to protected.

Comment: Thanks, I will make the whole class a friend, because I am not allowed to make the function protected.

Comment: `protected` won't work. Objects of derived types have access to **their own** inherited protected members, but not to other objects' protected members. `child->some_private` attempts to use a different object's protected member, so isn't allowed.

Comment: @PeteBecker `child` is of type `Base` -- the superclass. So you're saying that a subclass can't access the superclass's protected members?

Comment: @JosephLarson -- no, that's not what I said. An object of a derived type can't access protected members of **another** object.

Comment: @PeteBecker I don't see how that applies to this case.

Comment: @JosephLarson -- did you try this before you posted it as an answer? `child` is not `this`. `this->some_private` would be okay if the access specifier was changed to `protected`; `child->some_private` would be attempting to access a protected field of some outside object that `child` points at, so the access is not allowed.

Comment: @PeteBecker Child points to the base class, though, so NO, it's NOT pointing to an outside object. Do I really need to code it for you?

Comment: Okay, I'm actually coding it, and I might be really wrong, will get back to you.

Comment: Don't confuse base **class** with base **object**.

Comment: @PeteBecker Okay, Pete is right. I'm surprised I've never hit this. You can access your base class's protected members inside yourself, but you can't access them inside someone else. So you can, for instance, do `this->protectedValue` but you can't do `someoneElse->protectedValue`, even when someone else points to your inheritance tree.